# Is it possible to allow mysql connection only from specific folder?

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, permissions

Is it possible to allow mysql connection only from specific folder? I want to make sure that connection to database is only from my secure folder. This folder has php script which will make mysql connection. The folder is created with root user and it has read only permission for PHP process (apache).

Answer (score 2):

### No

As far as I know the current working directory is not something you can use as a security / authentication attribute in MySQL.